# Error: Parse error on line 1: [object Object] -^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']', got 'undefined'

Tags: next.js, readfile

i have "flask.json" file:

```json
{
    "title": "All About Flask",
    "date": "10 April 2023",
    "content": "Flask is a micro web framework written in Python. It is classified as a microframework because it does not require particular tools or libraries.[2] It has no database abstraction layer, form validation, or any other components where pre-existing third-party libraries provide common functions. However, Flask supports extensions that can add application features as if they were implemented in Flask itself.",
    "author": "Kanha Mishra"
}
```

why this give an error like this

i am unable to display data of my file on the browser using this file .
When i read this file from file system and try to access the route it throws an error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
[object Object]
-^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you're trying to use